# Not able to reload UICollectionView on button tap

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

I have one toggle button. Initially, it will be in off mode. So when I turn on my toggle I need to pass a set of data to collection view. And when its tun off again I need to pass a set of data to collection view.

So here is my code :

```
@IBAction func cateSelTap(_ sender: Any) {

     isChecked = !isChecked
     if isChecked {
        self.subsetTheCategoryListForClientLogin(isCityLogin: false)
     }else {
        self.subsetTheCategoryListForClientLogin(isCityLogin: true)
     }
}

    func subsetTheCategoryListForClientLogin(isCityLogin: Bool) {
        let cityType = "city"
        print("LOG:CATE1 \(self.categoryarr)")
        var objectIds = [Int]()
        var subsetArray = NSMutableArray()
        for i in 0..<self.categoryarr.count {
            let type = (self.categoryarr.object(at:i) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "type") as! String
            if isCityLogin {
                if type == cityType {
                    subsetArray.add(self.categoryarr.object(at:i) as AnyObject)
                    objectIds.append(i)
                }
            } else {
                if type != cityType {
                    subsetArray.add(self.categoryarr.object(at:i) as AnyObject)
                    objectIds.append(i)
                }
            }
        }
        self.categoryarr.removeAllObjects()
        self.categoryarr = subsetArray
        print("LOG:CATE2 \(self.categoryarr)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.categorycollection.reloadData()
//            self.categorycollection.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(self.categorycollection.reloadData), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)

        }
    }
```

When I run my app, and when I turn off - my collection view data is not showing exact data..still it is showing previous data. Again when I turn off its fully blank.

Any help on this?

Comment: Seems like you are calling `subsetTheCategoryListForClientLogin:` with same parameter in both conditions of button action. Also you are applying filter on `self.categoryarr` and assigning the results to itself. This is the cause the collection becomes blank after some on/off cycle.

Comment: yes, i am passing the bool  values in to it. based on that bool val only my data will be sending to coll view

Comment: @Akhilrajtr  yes, bec in my collection view i am using  categoryarr to show the values in my collection view cell.So only i assigned to categoryarr. if that is off then bool values will be false. And if that is on bool values wil be true. Based on bool val only i am appending data .

Comment: If you need to filter the original array with condition and display the filtered items in collectionview, use a different array as collection view source and keep the original datasource as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new property like `categoryarr`, say `categoryCollectionViewSource` and assign initial data to it. Use `categoryCollectionViewSource` in collection view delegate methods instead of `categoryarr`. And in the filter method

```
func subsetTheCategoryListForClientLogin(isCityLogin: Bool) {

    let cityType = "city"
    print("LOG:CATE1 \(self.categoryarr)")
    var objectIds = [Int]()
    var subsetArray = NSMutableArray()
    for i in 0..<self.categoryarr.count {
        let type = (self.categoryarr.object(at:i) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "type") as! String
        if isCityLogin {
            if type == cityType {
                subsetArray.add(self.categoryarr.object(at:i) as AnyObject)
                objectIds.append(i)
            }
        } else {
            if type != cityType {
                subsetArray.add(self.categoryarr.object(at:i) as AnyObject)
                objectIds.append(i)
            }
        }
    }
    //note this line
    self.categoryCollectionViewSource.removeAllObjects()
    self.categoryCollectionViewSource = subsetArray
    print("LOG:CATE2 \(self.categoryarr)")
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.categorycollection.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: `categoryCollectionViewSource` is what type of property ??

Comment: same as `categoryarr` property.

Comment: i tried, but i am getting crash like in cell for index method index range [0.. 3] like that

Comment: you might be still using `categoryarr` in collectionview delegate/datasource methods.

Comment: I fixed it...can u please help me on here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590016/search-bar-is-happening-when-enter-the-exact-case-text.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func cateSelTap(_ sender: Any) {
      isChecked = !isChecked
   if isChecked {
         self.subsetTheCategoryListForClientLogin(isCityLogin: false)
   } else {
         self.subsetTheCategoryListForClientLogin(isCityLogin: true)
   }
}
```

Comment: its having same in my post. What else is added ??

Comment: You had `isCityLogin: false` twice; this one has `false` then `true`. If this is the solution, it would have been nice to point this out.

Comment: i have changed, then also no success